# Ajax error redirecting in IE and posting get instead of post after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got AJAX posting but it's getting redirected with get request not post request. What is going on?

Below is my code:

```
$.ajax({
                      type: "post",
                      url: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ajax_free_quote_form.php',
                      data: "url="+url+"&name="+name+"&phone="+phone+"&email="+email+"&kw="+kw+"&x_url="+x_url,
                      success: function(data){
                            if (data == '3'){
                                $("#content .free_seo_quote form #step2").css({display:'none'});
                                $("#content .free_seo_quote form #step3").css({display:'block'});
                                $("#content .free_seo_quote form").append("<div style='display:none'><iframe src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/thankyou.html' name='' width='1px' height='1px'> </iframe></div>");
                            }
                            else{
                                $("#content .free_seo_quote form #step2").css({display:'none'});
                                $("#content .free_seo_quote form #step3").css({display:'block'});
                            }
                        }
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'http://www.rankreport.com.au/ajax/add_new_lead',
                    data: 'lead_company_id=41&lead_business='+url+'&lead_first_name='+name+'&lead_website='+url+'&lead_phone='+phone+'&lead_email='+email+'&lead_package=seo',
                    success: function(data) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: OK I'm getting this error in IE9 - Line: 127
Character: 344
Code: 0
Error Message: Access is denied.

URL: http://www.seoagency.com.sg/wp-content/themes/seoagency/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Try once using xmlhttp object:

```
var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
 document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

  }
  } 
 var user = document.getElementById("userid").value; 
 var usernm = document.getElementById("username").value; 
 if(usernm.split(" ").length==1)
{
 var pwd = document.getElementById("password").value; 
 var ath = document.getElementById("authority").value; 
 var email = document.getElementById("emailid").value; 
 var params = "user=" + user + "&usernm=" + usernm + "&pwd=" + pwd + "&ath=" + ath + "&email=" + email; 
 xmlhttp.open("POST","insertdb.php",true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send(params);
```